# Pseudo PHP regexp

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find the right regexp with php to check a pseudo. It should be between 4 and 64 characters, have alphanumeric characters (case-sensitive) and underscore. I tried these ones:

```
preg_match ( "/^([[[:alnum:]]_]){4, 64}$/", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "/^([a-zA-Z0-9_]){4, 64}$/", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "/^[[[:alnum:]]_]{4, 64}$/", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{4, 64}$/", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "/^([[[:alnum:]]_]){4,64}$/", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "/^([a-zA-Z0-9_]){4,64}$/", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "/^[[[:alnum:]]_]{4,64}$/", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,64}$/", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "#^([[[:alnum:]]_]){4, 64}$#", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "#^([a-zA-Z0-9_]){4, 64}$#", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "#^[[[:alnum:]]_]{4, 64}$#", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "#^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{4, 64}$#", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "#^([[[:alnum:]]_]){4,64}$#", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "#^([a-zA-Z0-9_]){4,64}$#", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "#^[[[:alnum:]]_]{4,64}$#", $pseudo )
preg_match ( "#^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,64}$#", $pseudo )
...
```

And many more, but no one works and I don't find why.

EDIT: My function is like that:

```
function pseudoIsAllowed($pseudo) {
    $res = true;
    echo "$pseudo\n";
    if (! preg_match ( "/^[[[:alnum:]]_]{4,64}$/", $pseudo ))
        $res = false;
    if ($res)
        echo "$pseudo is allowed.\n";
    else
        echo "$pseudo is NOT allowed.\n";
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no one works"? `preg_match ( "#^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,64}$#", $pseudo )` seems to be valid

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but could you explain what a `pseudo` is that you are checking? Could you provide some examples of it too?

Comment: For example, kndmsj is not accepted, malarzm is not accepted, SWLim is not accepted, fgrdfgnreg is not accepted...

Comment: The last one works well - http://ideone.com/D5T6M7. POSIX character class can be used like this: `'~^[[:alnum:]_]{4,64}$~'`. Or just use \w (equal to `[[:alnum:]_]`) shorthand.

Comment: All your examples match perfectly fine in `preg_match ( "#^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,64}$#", $pseudo )` as mentioned by @malarzm Something else must be causing an issue if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that /^[[:alnum:]_]{4,64}$/ works. Maybe it was a cache issue or something like that. Thank you all though.